# Why is Edward in a white limousine at the end of the film?

Tags: props, pretty-woman

In [*Pretty Woman*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100405/), the limousine that is available to Edward while he is in Beverly Hills for the week is Gray in color and is driven all week by a chauffeur named Darryl.

During the final scene of the film, a white limousine pulls up to Vivian's apartment building with Darryl driving it.

**Why is Edward suddenly in a white limousine?  Does the color of the limousine have any significance or was it just an oversight by filmmakers?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Earlier in the movie, Vivian says

> When I was a little girl, my mama used to lock me in the attic when I was bad, which was pretty often.
>
> And I would-- I would pretend I was a princess...trapped in a tower by a wicked queen. And then suddenly this knight... on a **white horse** with these bright colors flying would come charging up and draw his sword.
>
> And I would wave.
>
> And he would climb up the tower and rescue me.
>
> <sup>[Transcript](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/p/pretty-woman-script-transcript-julia.html)</sup>

So when Edward arrives, he's in a white limo (to represent the horse) and carrying an umbrella(?) as a sword, and perhaps the flowers (as bright colors) and then climbs her building (the tower) to resue her from her "prison".

[image]

> "Why is Edward suddenly in a white limousine?", I suspect that Edward rented specifically to playfully fulfill her childhood fantasy.
>
> <sup>BrettFromLA in a comment</sup>

This is the most reasonable interpretation. Having realised he's in love with Vivian, he sets out, in the only way he knows how, to fulfill the previously stated dream.

Comment: And as to the O.P.'s question, "Why is Edward suddenly in a white limousine?", I suspect that Edward rented specifically to playfully fulfill her childhood fantasy.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Thanks...I should have stated that. I've included your comment with acknowledgement.

Answer (score 13):

**He's riding in like a knight in shining armour to rescue his princess.**

The limousine is white because, in the more traditional children's stories, the knight's horse is often depicted as being white (part and parcel of the term "white knight.")

He's also standing up through the sunroof as though he were riding *on* the limo instead of simply sitting in it, and (as you can see in the clip) he even goes to the extent of climbing out of the sunroof and jumping down, rather than using the door to get out.  These details further establish the metaphor of the limo as a "horse" to Richard Gere's "knight."

In-universe, the argument could easily be made that he deliberately changed to a new limo in order to make this exact impression as he came to pick up his love.

Comment: This answer is spot on, though Edward is obviously being very sexist and misogynistic here--then again, the 90s were a very sexist and misogynistic time!